# Transfer confirm on mobile wallet using walletconnect shows ethereum address

Tags: tron, wallet-connect

I am trying to connect DAPP with trustwallet mobile app using walletconnect. I am used the demo app provided by tronwallet-adapter here https://github.com/tronprotocol/tronwallet-adapter/tree/main/demos/react-ui/create-react-app.

I tested connecting my trustwallet with the walletconnect qr code shown and the connection was successfull. When I tried to transfer TRC to the receiver address, I get a confirmation notification on my trustwallet app. But I see details are incorrect there. It is showing my ethereum wallet address in From field.

Is the details shown in confirm screen correct? Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is my wallet connector config

```
const walletConnectAdapter = new WalletConnectAdapter({ 
network: 'Mainnet',
 options: { relayUrl: 'wss://relay.walletconnect.com', 
projectId: '****',
 metadata: { name: 'Test DApp',
 description: 'JustLend WalletConnect',
 url: 'https://your-dapp-url.org/',
 icons: ['https://your-dapp-url.org/mainLogo.svg'],
 },
 }, 
});
```

Below is the screenshot of what I am seeing on mobile.

[image]